# Unable to delete multiple li from ul

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-lists, removechild

I'm creating a to-do list for class:

> Lab 4: Todo List Let's make a simple todo-list which supports the
> following operations: add an item to the list remove an item from the
> list mark an item as completed Removed items should disappear
> entirely. Completed items should appear at the bottom (or in a
> separate list) with a line through them.

I'm unable to remove multiple li from my ul. I get an error after removing the first.

> lab-04.js:16 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on
> 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node. at
> HTMLButtonElement.removeBtn.onclick
> (http://127.0.0.1:5500/js/lab-04/lab-04.js:16:18)

Oddly, enough the buttons are removed without much fuss.

The code (js):

```
let manipulateDom = () => {
    let container = document.getElementsByClassName('container')
    let toDoList = document.getElementById('to-do')
    let removeBtn = document.createElement('button')

    content = document.getElementById('userInput').value
    listItem = document.createElement('li')
    listItem.className = 'list-item'
    listItem.textContent = (content)

    removeBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('remove'))

    removeBtn.onclick = function() {
        toDoList.removeChild(removeBtn)
        
        toDoList.removeChild(listItem)
    
    }


    

    toDoList.appendChild(listItem)
    toDoList.appendChild(removeBtn)

    
}
```

(html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>lab-04</title>
    <script src='/js/lab-04/lab-04.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>To Do List</h4>
    <input type='text' id='userInput' placeholder="item to add">
    <input type="submit" onclick="manipulateDom()">

    <ul id='to-do'>
    </ul>

    <ul id='done'>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, ready to pull my hair out

Comment: One thing to consider.  When the user clicks the remove button, what would be the value of the `toDoList` variable?  Does it exist at that time or only during the code that creates the listItem and removeBtn items?  The same goes for those two variables as well.  Think about the **scope** that these variables are in.

Comment: Could you confirm if `listItem` is in the `window` scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting your `listItem` in the `window` scope, and what `removeBtn.onclick` does is removing the `listItem` in the `window` scope, that's why the remove button only works once and only works on the last element created.

Declare `listItem` in the block scope and it should be working again

```js
let manipulateDom = () => {
    let container = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
    let toDoList = document.getElementById('to-do');
    let removeBtn = document.createElement('button');

    let content = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
    let listItem = document.createElement('li');
    
    listItem.className = 'list-item';
    listItem.textContent = (content);

    removeBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode('remove'))

    removeBtn.onclick = function() {
        toDoList.removeChild(removeBtn);
        toDoList.removeChild(listItem);
    };

    toDoList.appendChild(listItem);
    toDoList.appendChild(removeBtn);
}
```

```html
<h4>To Do List</h4>
<input type='text' id='userInput' placeholder="item to add">
<input type="submit" onclick="manipulateDom()">

<ul id='to-do'>
</ul>

<ul id='done'>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So, in summary I needed to specify my content and listItem were variables! Simple solution, much appreciated